# How do get a id through a prototype function parameter?

Tags: javascript, prototype

Hello just working through my Javascript stuff , ran into an little issue which doesn't make any sense why it wouldn't be working?.

I would like to use id "prototype function parameter" through my prototype function body but it doesn't work for some reason?, is this a syntax error what am I missing also where can I learn more about this simply?.

```
function BG(type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    BG.prototype.RootFrame = function (x, y, size, title, id) {
        // document.write("hello!" + x);
        var RF = document.getElementsByTagName(id);
        RF.innerHTML = 'Hello!';
    };

    var BG = new BG();

    var execute = function () {
        BG.RootFrame(0, 0, 0, 0, 'test');
    };

    if (!!(window.addEventListener))
        window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", execute)
    else
        window.attachEvent("onload", execute)
```

This code works :

```
function BG(type) {
    this.type = type;
}

BG.prototype.RootFrame = function (x, y, size, title, id) {
    // document.write("hellocrap!" + x);
    var RF = document.getElementById(id);
    RF.innerHTML = 'Hello!';
};

var BG = new BG();

var execute = function () {
    BG.RootFrame(0, 0, 0, 0, 'test');
};

if (!!(window.addEventListener))
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", execute)
else
    window.attachEvent("onload", execute)
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/t1tcgjg1/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you are sending an id of an element, and you want to use getElementsByTagName to select that element.

Try using getElementById instead.

Also, since you want to work with prototype... you can just use $("yourIdHere").

Also a note... the id you are looking for must exist before running the script (so you should call the function after page was loaded).

Comment: There's no s in `getElementById()`

Comment: Wait what I thought prototype was a separate distinct library unrelated to prototype functions?

By the way your getElementsById doesn't appear to be working but I'll keep trying .

Oh !! right sorry lol yes.. pstenstrm you are correct.

Comment: Miss typed thank you. @Dominic Huges, read pstenstrm comment. I typed it wrong (edited in answer also) :).

Answer (score 0):

getElementsByTagName waits a "html tag" and 'test' seems to be smthg like an ID.

Try use getElementsById instead!

PS:

```
var BG = new BG();
var bg = new BG(); // better ;-)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an element `<test></test>` in html, it works fine, just get first node `[0]`, because `getElementsBytagName` returns all elements in the document

```
var RF = document.getElementsByTagName(id)[0];
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rL0ttqzo/1/)

Comment: True but... why would you do that? Unless you do some really custom things (so in like... 99% of cases) it is no use.